# Any way to add a static library to a dynamic library without rebuilding dynamic library?

Tags: linux, cmake, linker, elf

Let's say I have a static library `libmystatic.a` and a dynamic library `libmydynamic.so`.
Is it possible to use command line tools like `ar` or `patchelf` etc to put the `libmystatic.a` archive into the dynamic library?

So it would be the equivalent of rebuilding `libmy_dynamic.so` and editing the `CMakeLists.txt` to add:

```
target_link_libraries(my_dynamic libmy_static.a)
```

But as I mentioned, I don't want to rebuild the lib. Is there anyway to do this from the command line?

Comment: I doubt it. The object files need to be compiled differently if they're going into a dynamic library versus static library.

Comment: This looks a bit like [the XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to link `libmydynamic.so` with `libmystatic.a` without recompiling `libmydynamic.so`?

Comment: Basically this problem has to do with a CI build which I've automated.
I first build mxnet with GPU support as a dynamic library then cache the library (and only rebuild on next CI build if my mxnet build script has changed).
I then build my own SDK library as a static library (this library changes on every CI build). Finally, I modify the mxnet cmake file to link my static library that I just built, then I rebuild the mxnet library.

Comment: The issue is that when I add my static sdk library to the `target_link_libraries` call then rebuild the mxnet library, it takes 30 minutes to rebuild, which is very long for a CI build. In the previous release (1.6) of mxnet the rebuild took less than a minute (so doing this was fine), but with their 1.7 release, it takes 30 minutes as it needs to rebuild several modules which it previously did not have to do.

Comment: (Maybe your code is written in C++? Then it is normal. Still, a shared object can use another shared object, and the latter can be rebuilt without changing the former.)

Comment: Yes my code is written in C++. Why does that change things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible

No (on most systems). No (on any ELF system).

A fully linked image (such as the executable or a shared library) is considered *final* -- the linker discards most of the info that you would need to rebuild it.

AIX is a notable exception -- rebuilding certain kinds of shared libraries is possible there.

Comment: Speaking of which, aix-relink.pl really needs to be updated for AIX 7 ;-)